# Does drafts' lifespans start from the initial draft or from the last edit?

Tags: support

I am currently writing a relatively big answer, so I am making use of drafts to work on it a bit everyday as I don't have much time.

I understand that drafts will be deleted after 7 days. What I don't understand is, will those 7 days start from the time I initially started to write the answer or will they reset every time I edit the draft?

Comment: Related - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251432/how-can-i-draft-multiple-posts. It could be more efficient to use text editor and save it there to avoid any confusion. In the [reference post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238) only week lifespan is mentioned.

Comment: ^^ I try not to rely too much on the draft system. I typically copy unfinished answers to a text file to save them for later, then paste them back to continue working on them.

Comment: Yep, sounds like your are asking for lost work. Relying on a draft system to safegard your work seems feeble at best and is bound to lead to sorrow. Use the editor but save it locally.

Comment: I took your advice and wrote everything locally instead. Other wise I would have been taking a risk with a 2000 word answer:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94991/trace-visualisation-in-3d-how-to-wrap-curves-onto-a-3d-mesh/95577#95577